# IntelliJ says 'cannot run program '/path/to/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh' error=13 permission denied

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

In intelliJ ulimate, running a bare bone spring mvc application I get the error:

```
'cannot run program '/path/to/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh' error=13 permission denied
```

How to I fix this? (i'm on a mac)

Comment: path/to/tomcat sounds like there is no tomcat instance installed/assigned in your eclipse

Comment: This is a problem at the OS level and so is bordering on being more appropriate for Super User.  While it *occurred* during development it's not strictly development-related.

Comment: @myself i ment intelliJ not eclipse of course

Comment: Redlab, path/to'tomcat is just a placeholder that I put, I have it installed.

Comment: Complementing the answer... If you prefer grant the execute permission only to the user (instead of granting to everybody). It also works. chmod u+x /path/to/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh

Answer (score 289, accepted):

In short, from a console:

`chmod a+x /path/to/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh`

This assumes that you 've elided the Tomcat path in your post, and checked that it really does exist on your system before posting here.  Depending on the existing permissions of the file, you may need to issue the above command as a user with sufficiently elevated privileges.

Comment: This worked fine on Mac. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

Solution: You set permission for Tomcat directory:

```
chmod -R 777 apache-tomcat-directory
```

Comment: After few years, I know that... Indeed, we only need set `*.bat` (on Windows operating system), or `*.sh` (on macOS, Linux operating system) more attribute `executable` is good enough.

Answer (score 20):

I meet this error today. It's because I take a wrong package of Tomcat6.
In Max OS, I should download the `tar.gz` , but I download the `zip`.
Make sure you get the right Tomcat package.

Comment: I also downloaded zip and there is no executable permission on any of the files. Downloading tar.gz showed proper executable permission on files. This is the best answer because it sets the proper file permission for all Tomcat files on Mac (not just catalina.sh). Otherwise, you have to manually `chmod +x` each file you want to make executable for user/group/world.

Comment: Thank you. it helped me

Comment: Helped me get unstuck as well!

Answer (score 12):

When I face with this problem I check:
[image]

Right click on catalina.sh -> Properties -> Permissions.

Comment: where to callout this panel?

Comment: @DmitMedv This user dialog is not accessible by right clicking the file from finder. How are you getting to this screen?

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick on Kubuntu (I am sure that it will work on any linux distro), but I wonder is necessary on Intellij since that is not necessary on Eclipse