# Tomcat error while running spring mvc web application on intelliJ 14

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have recently set up Spring MVC on intelliJ but whenever I run the project using Tomcat server, it gives the following error:

> Error running Tomcat 8.0.171: Cannot run program
>   "/Library/Tomcat/bin/catalina.sh" (in directory
>   "/Library/Tomcat/bin"): error=13, Permission denied

The error seems to me that it has to do with permission issue.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried checking the OS permissions of the catalina.sh file?  Is it executable by the user running the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ says 'cannot run program '/path/to/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh' error=13 permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092049/intellij-says-cannot-run-program-path-to-tomcat-bin-catalina-sh-error-13-per)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should chmod it.

```
chmod a+x /Library/Tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
```