# Start tomcat in intellij community edition

Tags: linux, intellij-idea

Hi am trying to start tomcat in intellij 14 community edition. I have configured it as an external tools. in windows I could do it with by pointing the program to catalina.bat and in parameters i could type jpda start. But in linux machine i am pointing the program to Catalina.sh and in parameters i am typing **jpda start**. 
But when i run it it is showing permission denied. Below is the exact error. how can i fix it?

Error:

Error running Tomcat: Cannot run program "/home/creative/work/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/bin/catalina.sh" (in directory "/home/creative/work/apache-tomcat-8.0.12/bin"): error=13, Permission denied

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ says 'cannot run program '/path/to/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh' error=13 permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092049/intellij-says-cannot-run-program-path-to-tomcat-bin-catalina-sh-error-13-per)

Comment: no luck for me. I tried it

Comment: What you actually tried? 'Permission denied' simply says that you don't have permission to run it, so you've to give the permission to it, either by `chmod 755 catalina.sh` or `chown $USER catalina.sh`. There shouldn't be any other magic here.

Comment: Hi Kenorb, I am new to linux. Sorry if my question is very silly. I gave permission to catalina.sh by running chmod u=rwx catalina.sh. but i need to give permission for whole directory as i am getting same error for other files. What should I execute?. I tried  sudo chmod u=rwx -R apache-tomcat-8.0.12 but still i am getting permission denied for catalina.out

Comment: Giving `rwx` to all files isn't advised. It's better if you re-edit your question and post the updated error. You can basically try to fix your ownership for all your files within your HOME folder, e.g.: `sudo chown -R creative /home/creative` where `creative` is your username.

Answer (score 0):

I gave a full permission to tomcat folder by executing the below command:

```
sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx  apache-tomcat-8.0.12 -R
```

And it worked for me. May be not a optimal solution as i am new to linux.

And thanks for kenorb for helping me to figure out the solution.